# Age of target audience of Adventure Time

Tags: adventure-time

What age is the target audience of Adventure Time?

Superficially it's children, but distinct from other such animated shows, including even ones like the Simpsons, I feel it's really older. As if the adult animators, story-borders etc... produced a show that they would like to watch.

Comment: Tom Kenny- "Some of the best animated works  are those that are subversive, where the humor and characters can appeal to both children and adults alike. How do you straddle the line between what appeals to children and adults? Is it something you’re conscious of when writing the episodes?
Pendleton Ward: I’m never trying to do anything. I’m just trying to make it funny. That’s all that I’m ever thinking about, is trying to make it fun and interesting for everyone to work on. I never think about it."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *official* **target audience** for Adventure Time is the boys 2-11 ("[childrens entertainment](http://www.nickandmore.com/2010/07/13/adventure-time-ratings-chart-april-5-july-12-2010/)") demographic.

According to [TVByTheNumbers](http://tvbythenumbers.zap2it.com/2012/04/04/cartoon-networks-adventure-time-season-4-premiere-tops-monday-ratings/127542/), The show was rated #1 for the following demo groups on all Monday night network television among boys **2-11, 6-11 & 9-14**.

The show was recently nominated for an Annie Award for **Best Animated Television Production for a Children's Audience**, a category that only applies to shows that are:

> "[especially produced for ages 6 through 12 years old](http://annieawards.org/rules-and-categories/)".

Comment: Thanks. So even if it has older bumps in popularity vs viewer age graph, the largest is for children 2 - 14, who it is officially for, however it is shown on children's TV and looks like a children's show. I'll accept this as correct if no other answers arrive in a few days.

Comment: I'd say that you'd have to in your 20s to really appreciate many themes of the show.

Comment: @alan2here - Like many children's shows, there are clearly "easter eggs" added for adult viewers

Comment: @alan2here - Almost all the older viewers are watching it on tivo or download. The number who're watching it in its official timeslot on children's television is vanishingly small.

Comment: Excellent point, stats would need to take those viewers into account too.

Comment: Not really eggs, they are major themes. How about, Fins sexual submission as a result of an early experience, and his general exploration of this as someone who has no friends on his level, Flame Princess being too volatile for anyone else and her sheltered upbringing, the gender neutral BMO, Marceline and the Ice King, the Ice King having alzhimers, and being a pedophile, but the way the world has to live with and help him anyway and he's is not just a villain. A stereotypically mentally retarded donut being the most respectful example of this sort of thing ...

Comment: ... I've seen on TV, where we have misrepresentative trash like The Big Bang Theory. Princess Bubblegums nuanced personality, The Glitch episode throughout, including with the pornography. Children's shows aren't supposed to feel so real as unlike everything else to be more more real, less fake, than reality, by communicating layers of mood that some of the children will reach, but not for another couple of decades.

Comment: Youtube - PBS Idea Channel - Has a couple of episodes on Adventure Time, one about BMO and another about how some of the feel, at least among older viewers is achieved by multiple layers of nostalgia, one for being young and playful, or still feeling it, and another by the characters themselves, for the time before the disaster.

Comment: minor nitpick, the site you linked to gives the demographic as "kids 2-11", not "boys 2-11". I get the impression it's one of those cartoons that isn't too strongly favored by one gender or the other.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - My understanding is that their key demo is boys. Although I can't find the quote from the show's production company to back it up (damnit), I've read multiple articles in magazines like "Retail Merchandiser" that confirm that the show is targeted at young males, **not** across genders.

Comment: But "targeted at young males" might refer to the marketing, rather than who the show creators are aiming their stories at, or what the viewing numbers actually are--I've read that with kids' shows, part of the reason they are often marketed specifically at boys is just because the marketers believe boys are more likely to buy toys than girls, even if they both like the show.

Comment: The creators, imho, are very obviously targeting boys. Not that anyone would have any trouble enjoying the show.

Also, the 2-14 crowd should not be overlooked I think if it did not have the art-style it has, and instead was live action I would expect a parental rating of over 14, at least. There are some episodes that were seriously disturbing. I consider it, by far, the most mature show on TV.

Comment: I would say, the writers obviously write it for an adult audience but make sure to make it enjoyable for kids. Most of the show is simply revolves around things that would be mostly lost on children, but being children they do not require the deepness of the plot that we enjoy. These complex and mature plots would just get screwed up and not work out as well as they do if they were not a priority.